# inputenc warning with utf8 engine

Tags: unicode

I aw writing a letter but when using `xelatex` I get

```
Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.
```

The code is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\signature{Randy}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Remove the calls to both `fontenc` and `inputenc` when running the document with `xelatex`.

Comment: XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX both recognize exactly one input encoding: UTF8. That's why anything contributed by the `inputenc` package is ignored. The warning message you see is trying to be helpful -- or, at least, informative.

Comment: Right @Mico  That worked as I had liked.  Have just installed auctex.  Do I need to make any customisations to emacs to use valuable auctex functionality?

Comment: @Randy - I'm afraid I've never used auctex. (Not even entirely sure what exactly it may be.) The last time I've used emacs was more than 20 years ago. Sorry.

Comment: Ok then.  I am writing in different languages in the same document, and found there are document classes with language specifications.  I do not know how people handle languages other than english or documents that include multiple languages.

Comment: the site format doesn't support asking new questions in comments. Feel free to post a new question, preferably with an example if you have questions about multi language documents but look for [babel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babel)